# PHPMailer mail not sent => Many errors

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I want to use the Mail function using PHPMailer in order to give an email confirmation for someone who filled a form.

Here's my send mail code =>

```
 /* some codes with already a phpmyadmin database and a form */


function send_mail($email,$message,$subject) // method called, ignore the param
    {                       
        require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 465; // for ssl
    $mail->Username = 'an_email_test_1@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password = 'pwd_of_username_just_above';

    $mail->SetFrom('an_email_test_1@gmail.com'); // same as ->Username
    $mail->Subject = "Test Mail";
    $mail->Body = "Hi.";
    $mail->AddAddress('an_email_test_2@gmail.com');

    if (!$mail->Send())
        return 'Mail error:' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    return 'Success, check your mail.';
}
```

I get a **"SMTP Class not found"** so I included right below the **require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');** =>

```
        require 'mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
```

and thanks the SMTPDebug enabled, it gives me this error >

```
2016-05-20 14:27:49 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP h4sm20018967wjz.20 - gsmtp 
2016-05-20 14:27:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO "name_of_my_virtualhost" (I use WAMP3.0.4)
2016-05-20 14:27:49 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [80.215.180.91] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 
2016-05-20 14:27:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 
2016-05-20 14:27:49 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 
2016-05-20 14:27:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: bG9nYW4ucGV5cnkxQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ== 2016-05-20 14:27:49 SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 
2016-05-20 14:27:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: Y29jaG9uOTM= 
2016-05-20 14:27:50 SERVER -> CLIENT: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 h4sm20018967wjz.20 - gsmtp 
2016-05-20 14:27:50 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 h4sm20018967wjz.20 - gsmtp 
2016-05-20 14:27:50 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 
2016-05-20 14:27:50 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 
2016-05-20 14:27:50 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection h4sm20018967wjz.20 - gsmtp 
2016-05-20 14:27:50 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I don't really know how to solve it, I just wanted to send a simple mail without any informations for now with 2 gmail address created especially for that. The n°1 as the sender and the n°2 as the recipient

Should I change something from the apache php.ini in the mail function or something else ? 
Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: It would help if you read [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) that the error message pointed you at, or any of the many duplicates of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you activeated the `php_openssl` extension in PHP

Using the menus do

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> PHP Extension -> php_openssl
```

If this menu item does not have a TICK beside it, click the `php_openssl` menu line and it will activate the extension and restart Apache for you so it see's the change.

You may also need to [Allow less secure password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255) on the accounts

Comment: I checked wampmanager settings and php_openssl was already marked.
Furthermore, thanks to you, I change the account security of my mail sender with your link and now I received from my mail n°2, the mail as I wanted.

Thanks for that but is it normal if the error message is still there with SMTPDebug ?